# Tomcat client cert validation

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have tomcat configured with clientAuth="want" , so that user can login with with CERT or without it . Now we have 
exposed REST service on seperate context and want service must be called with client CERT , so we have written
authentication filter for rest service and we are checking whether user has called service with CERT or not as below

```
request.getAttribute(javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate);
```

1. So is it enough to check the only certificate is present in the request or do we also have to validate that certificate? Since our understanding is tomcat validates at handshake level and will not allow the invalid certificate to pass through?
2. Does tomcat only validate cert against trustStore or it validates all aspects like expiry, issuer?
3. Does tomcat validate whether the certificate is revoked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat will not pass the request to you unless the certificate is valid, so you're good there.

It can also check if it's revoked, but you'll need to specify revocation list for that to work (SSLCARevocationFile).